# How do I update an app based on the aurelia skeleton to the new skeleton version?

Tags: npm, aurelia

I have an application based on skeleton-esnext-webpack - so I downloaded the skeleton, copied it and then applied my changes to start building my app.

A new version of the skeleton has been released in Git.

How can I apply the new released version to my application?

I'm hoping there's an easier way than having to download the new version and then reinstall all the modules I've added and my app src.

Running npm update doesn't move the skeleton to the new release.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `npm update` will update the npm packages. To update the skeleton you'd have to download the new skeleton and copy-paste your src folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first installed the skeleton, how did you install it (`npm` or `git clone`)?  As +Fabio pointed out, `npm` won't update to a new repo.  I believe the the exact skeleton you mentioned (`skeleton-esnext-webpack`) is actually part of the `skeleton-navigation` repo now, which further complicates it.

To use a new skeleton, you should definitely download the new skeleton (using `npm` or `git clone`) and then copy your `src` folder into the new one.  You'll also need to compare your `aurelia.json` files, install any missing dependencies, and add them to the new `aurelia.json` manually.

If you need help in this process, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!